# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim.class

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded the new preview for Android Studio 2.2 and built my project, when I hit this gradle error:

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim.class

This is the ./gradlew app:dependencies report: http://pastebin.com/hU5KYFsN

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.fernandocejas.frodo'
apply plugin: 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'

apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            //Removed
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.usehomeroom.vasuki"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
    }
}

dependencies {

    //Support
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0"
    compile "com.android.support:design:23.4.0"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0"

    //UI
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.adaptercommands:adaptercommands:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.hannesdorfmann:adapterdelegates2:2.0.0'

    //Data
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0"
//    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.4'

    //Search
    compile 'com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.2@aar'

    //Observables
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay:rxrelay:1.1.0'

    //DI
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    //Testing
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

    //Monitor
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.2'
//    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$firebase_version"
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'net.ypresto.timbertreeutils:timbertreeutils:1.0.0'

    //Util
    compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.fernandocejas:arrow:1.0.0'
    apt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
    provided 'com.jakewharton.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.2-update1'
    apt 'frankiesardo:auto-parcel:1.0.1'
    compile 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
    provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'

    //Auth
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0"
    compile "com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.7.0@aar"
    compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.9@aar'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've tried cleaning my project multiple times, even from the terminal, and manually deleting my build folders. I switched back to Android Studio 2.1 but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I find that this often happens if there is a version clash in (transitive) dependencies. Could you show use the dependency tree for your project? Run `./gradlew app:dependencies` (or just `gradle` if you're not using the wrapper, and substitute `app` with the actual module name of your app project).

Comment: Also, iirc, you can configure your project to eagerly fail on version conflicts to get more details on which dependencies actually conflict. I think it was just a matter of adding `configurations.all { resolutionStrategy { failOnVersionConflict() } }` to your `build.gradle`, but do a google search for some more pointers.

Comment: @MH. I've edited the dependency tree into the post. http://pastebin.com/hU5KYFsN

Comment: I get an Error:A conflict was found between the following modules:
 - org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.6
 - org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.8 when I add the failOnVersionConflict resolutionStrategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with a bad dependency. https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-android/issues/88.